# Highlight Undefined Javascript Variables in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, local-variables

One of my faviourite mistakes in Javascript is to forget to define variables I am using **locally** in a function. As you all know, due to scope, this is not always an error.

Is there any way in Visual Studio Code to highlight variables that are not defined in the function?

For example, say I have the function:

```
function MyFunction(argument1){ /* Note: not argument5 */
    var i; /* Note: not j */
    var arr1 = []; /* Note: not arr2 */

    ... /*Exciting code in between */

    len = 7;

    for(j=0;j<len;j++){
        arr2[j] = "Wibble" + argument5;
    }
}
```

I want `len`, `j`, `arr2` and `argument5` all to be highlighted in some way to show they are not defined locally in the function.

Comment: If I try in my VSC 1.53.2 these variables all have a red squiggle

Comment: How? Do you have a plug-in? Is it a setting? In my base VSC 1.54.3, there is no underline squiggle.

Comment: the only setting I have changed is `js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs`

Comment: Where do I find that? I cannot see it in my `settings.json`.

Comment: in settings page search for `javascript check`

Comment: I had to install the TsLint extension and then approve it to get error highlighting.

Comment: @GailFoad Thanks for the reply. I have now installed TsLint 1.3.3. I have enabled it for javascript. The global variables are still not highlighted. What do I do? I do not know what you mean by 'appove it'.

Comment: @Rewind  TsLint has stopped working for me. Try ESLint v2.1.20. (I can't remember what I did with the approve thing. I didn't need to do this with ESLint.)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Enable `JS/TS › Implicit Project Config: Check JS` in vscode settings.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you @farhan ali . This is going to help me so much. And thank you for looking at and answering older unanswered threads.

Comment: Just Enable and found tiny bugs which were causing me so much pain, Thanks @farhan Ali, It was frustrating to find bugs left by other devs or me for variables that do not belong to that file.

Comment: That should really be turned on by default.

Comment: This seems to work but it finds a ton of "errors" that are actually fine, especially when dealing with  querySelector results on unknown types so I had to turn it off.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is using eslint. Just add the dependency to your `package.json` devDependencies. optionally you can use a preset package such as the airbnb one I'm using or define the eslint rule [no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) inside the `.eslintrc.js` file.

Also, don't forget to install [the eslint vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

[image]

Comment: Adding ESlint as an extension to the VS code works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't know this rule exists and also is part of  `eslint:recommended`.
Have been very comfortable having TypeScript for a while, and currently need to go back maintaining an old JS project.