# VSCode isn't showing inline errors for Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm expecting red lines underlining errors in my Javascript code, however this isn't happening. It will show at runtime in the browser though.

[image]

I've tried searching in the settings for 'error' and 'errorSquiggles', all the things the google results seem to suggest. It seems VSCode has changed alot since and those options no longer exist.

For example:

```
    "javascript.validate.enable": true
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe this could help. Look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69671885/2159528